# Creating multidimensional arrays similair to matlab

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have this MatLab-Code and I need to do the same with Python.

```
for t = 1:AnzahlSegA     zsegaussen{t,1} = werteAussen(t,SpalteSegStartA):Abstandrechnung:werteAussen(t,SpalteSegEndeA);
```

This code creates an array with t*1 dimensions and fills each row with numbers. it starts at a given number (the first cell) and adds more numbers according to the stepsize ( in this case Abstandsrechnung) till it reaches the end value. WerteAussen is a Matrix which contains the needed information.

I wanted to the same with python but couldnt come up with something good. my best effort is this

```py
zsegmente = [[] for i in range(row)]
while listenstart < row and p < row:
    x: int
    for x in range(int(AllesAussen.iloc[p, 0]), int(AllesAussen.iloc[p, 1]), Schrittweite):
        zsegmente[listenstart].append(x)
        if len(zsegmente[listenstart]) == (int(AllesAussen.iloc[p, 1] - int(AllesAussen.iloc[p, 0])) / Schrittweite):
            listenstart += 1
            p += 1
print(zsegmente)
```

my idea was to have a list which contains lists which have the same information as each row in the array. as it turned out this is not easy to use anmd modify so I really need to get a multy dimensional array somehow.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at numpy arrays? The only "challenge" is knowing the number of rows and columns you need in advance to allocate the array.

Comment: Check out Numpy. It has ndarrays which are the multi-dimensional arrays I think you are looking for.

Comment: Damn autocorrect.  What i wanted to say is that i imported numpy but had trouble using it tocreate an array that wasnt predefined and also fill it with the numbers the way that i need to